# Black and White Ordered Hit Count Equality

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose you have a cubic bipartite graph. The vertices are coloured, black and white. Now let's look at the counts on the sets of black and white vertices that come up in cyclic paths. Some numerics indicate, that the sets are equal in the sense, that the ordered (monotonically increasing) hit count in one set equals the ordered hit count in the other.

How to prove that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question precisely, but every cycle in a bipartite graph is of even length, so contains equal numbers of white and black vertices.

Comment: @saulspatz you can meet several vertices several times, so it is not just the overall sum but the distribution of hits over the vertices...

Comment: I do't understand what you mean.  Can you give an example?

Comment: @saulspatz take [the cube k=3](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/cube-graphs). Black vertices have a odd number of 1's if you go cyclic like 0-1-3-2-0-1-5-4(-0) (I did bin2dec), you get the following pattern: [2 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 0] (black&white alternate)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.  There are a lot of cycles in the graph, and you seem to only be considering one of them.  Also, I don't understand  how the pattern arises, what the "hit count" is supposed to be, or what you assert to be true.

Comment: @saulspatz yes I mean the cyclic path you get when you go like 000-001-011-010-000-001-101-100(-000). We don't reach 110 and 111 which is 6 and 7, so at these positions in the pattern I get a 0. 000 and 001, which is 0 and 1 are met twice, so I get 2 at these positions in the pattern. All others are met once...

Comment: So you are saying that for any integer $k$, the number of white vertices traversed $k$ times is the same as the number of black vertices traversed $k$ times?  Have I got it now?

Comment: @saulspatz yes...